# Betfair like Odds increment and decrement

Tags: javascript, jquery, betfair

Please help me it is very irritating. Don't know why my logic is failed every time. 
I am trying to make Betfair like odds increment in my web project. Betfair have it's own price group which can be found here

> LINK:  https://api.developer.betfair.com/services/webapps/docs/display/1smk3cen4v3lu3yomq5qye0ni/Betfair+Price+Increments

Here is explanation: 
if odds is 1.01 and some body want to increase that odds via html5 number spinner the increment will be 0.01 and if odds is 2 the increment will be 0.02. whole increment list is available in that link.
working example can be found in betfair's betslip.

here is my Javascript:

```
function getIncremantal(fval) {
    var val = parseFloat(fval);
    var step;
    if (val <= 1.99) {
        step = 0.01;
    } else if (val > 2 && val < 3) {
        step = 0.02;
    } else if (val > 3 && val < 4) {
        step = 0.05;
    } else if (val > 4 && val < 6) {
        step = 0.1;
    } else if (val > 6 && val < 10) {
        step = 0.2;
    } else if (val > 10 && val < 19.5) {
        step = 0.5;
    } else if (val >= 20 && val < 30) {
        step = 1;
    } else if (val >= 30 && val < 50) {
        step = 2;
    } else if (val >= 50 && val < 100) {
        step = 5;
    } else if (val >= 100 && val < 1000) {
        step = 10;
    } else if (val > 1000) {
        step = null;
    }
    return step;
}
```

> Update: jsFiddle 
>   http://jsfiddle.net/71fs0a67/1/

Comment: What if `val` equals 2, 3, 4, etc...?

Comment: for info, betfair doesn't use a number input it uses a text input and custom up/down controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following which is not using number stepping, but if you use the buttons it does work. It is an alternate solution, sorry if its not what you are looking for.

HTML:

```
<input type="number" min="1.01" max="1000" id="num"/>
<button class="increment">+</button>
<button class="decrement">-</button>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.increment').on('click', function() {
    var elem = $('#num');
    var value = parseFloat(elem.val());
    var result = +(value + getIncremantal(value)).toFixed(2);
    elem.val(result);
});

$('.decrement').on('click', function() {
    var elem = $('#num');
    var value = parseFloat(elem.val());
    var result = +(value - getDecremantal(value)).toFixed(2);
    elem.val(result);
});

function getIncremantal(val) {
    var step;
    if (val < 2) {
        step = 0.01;
    } else if (val >= 2 && val < 3) {
        step = 0.02;
    } else if (val >= 3 && val < 4) {
        step = 0.05;
    } else if (val >= 4 && val < 6) {
        step = 0.1;
    } else if (val >= 6 && val < 10) {
        step = 0.2;
    } else if (val >= 10 && val < 20) {
        step = 0.5;
    } else if (val >= 20 && val < 30) {
        step = 1;
    } else if (val >= 30 && val < 50) {
        step = 2;
    } else if (val >= 50 && val < 100) {
        step = 5;
    } else if (val >= 100 && val < 1000) {
        step = 10;
    } else if (val > 1000) {
        step = null;
    }
    return step;
}

function getDecremantal(val) {
    var step;
    if (val <= 2) {
        step = 0.01;
    } else if (val > 2 && val <= 3) {
        step = 0.02;
    } else if (val > 3 && val <= 4) {
        step = 0.05;
    } else if (val > 4 && val <= 6) {
        step = 0.1;
    } else if (val > 6 && val <= 10) {
        step = 0.2;
    } else if (val > 10 && val <= 20) {
        step = 0.5;
    } else if (val > 20 && val <= 30) {
        step = 1;
    } else if (val > 30 && val <= 50) {
        step = 2;
    } else if (val > 50 && val <= 100) {
        step = 5;
    } else if (val > 100 && val <= 1000) {
        step = 10;
    } else if (val > 1000) {
        step = null;
    }
    return step;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/71fs0a67/7/

With jquery ui spinner, you can do something like this:

```
$( "#spinner" ).spinner({
    min: 1.01,
    max: 1000,
    step: 0.01,
    spin: function( event, ui ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        var value = this.value || ui.value;
        value = parseFloat(value);
        var step;
        if ($(event.currentTarget).hasClass('ui-spinner-up')) {
            step = getIncremantal(value);
            value = +(value + step).toFixed(2);
            $( "#spinner" ).spinner('value', value);
        } else {
            step = getDecremantal(value);
            value = +(value - step).toFixed(2);
            $( "#spinner" ).spinner('value', value);
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/71fs0a67/9/

Comment: If this is the answer you are looking for, please could you accept?

Answer (score 1):

Your code will return `undefined` for whole numbers.

Change all instances of  `val > number`  to `val >= number`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function getIncremantal(fval) {
    var val = parseFloat(fval);
    var step;
    if (val < 2) {
        step = 0.01;
    } else if (val >= 2 && val < 3) {
        step = 0.02;
    } else if (val >= 3 && val < 4) {
        step = 0.05;
    } else if (val >= 4 && val < 6) {
        step = 0.1;
    } else if (val >= 6 && val < 10) {
        step = 0.2;
    } else if (val >= 10 && val < 20) {
        step = 0.5;
    } else if (val >= 20 && val < 30) {
        step = 1;
    } else if (val >= 30 && val < 50) {
        step = 2;
    } else if (val >= 50 && val < 100) {
        step = 5;
    } else if (val >= 100 && val < 1000) {
        step = 10;
    } else if (val > 1000) {
        step = null;
    }
    return step;
}

function getDecremantal(fval) {
    var val = parseFloat(fval);
    var step;
    if (val <= 2) {
        step = 0.01;
    } else if (val > 2 && val <= 3) {
        step = 0.02;
    } else if (val > 3 && val <= 4) {
        step = 0.05;
    } else if (val > 4 && val <= 6) {
        step = 0.1;
    } else if (val > 6 && val <= 10) {
        step = 0.2;
    } else if (val > 10 && val <= 20) {
        step = 0.5;
    } else if (val > 20 && val <= 30) {
        step = 1;
    } else if (val > 30 && val <= 50) {
        step = 2;
    } else if (val > 50 && val <= 100) {
        step = 5;
    } else if (val > 100 && val <= 1000) {
        step = 10;
    } else if (val > 1000) {
        step = null;
    }
    return step;
}
```

Comment: no dear. i already tried this logic. this logic failed on decrement. like if my value is 3.05 and i am trying to decrement this, it goes to 3 and which is good but when i again trying to decrement it goes to 2.95 which is invalid odd. it should be like 2.98 with 0.02 step value. you can visit betfair.com and check working demo on betslip.

Comment: i will upload on jsfiddle for better understanding.

Comment: I have modified my logic for increment and decrement with different functions, guessing thats what you might need. I didnt go through the entire betting logic. But based on your comment, this might do the trick?

Comment: I am using html5 input[type=number] and i think there is no decrement event for that.

Comment: I tried different things, but if you are using HTML5 number, I cant think of a solution yet, since there is no way you can identify whether its a stepUp or a stepDown

Comment: Thank you for your time. Is there any way to use jquery ui spinner? i can't use separate buttons.